# Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused"

Tags: java, spring, macos, intellij-idea, minikube

I've been having this problem while trying to debug Minikube pods on Intellij for the past couple of days. On a fresh computer start, everything is fine but if a connection to a pod stops abruptly during the debug process, I am not able to connect again to the environment. I get the following message;

```
Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused"
```

Now, my reflex was to check which process was listening to the port 5005 with the command

```
lsof -i:5005
```

But nothing is listening to this port.

```
sudo lsof | grep localhost
```

Doesn't return either any process listing to the port in question.

- I tried to kill all java and idea process without success. I checked the option *kill the debug process immediately* in Intellij preferences settings.
- I tried to change localhost to 127.0.0.1
- I tried changing the port to listen to, sometimes it works, other times not.
- I tried npx kill-port 5005
- No debug process is active in Intellij, tried the STOP ALL button.

Anyone has faced a similar problem and found a solution about the problem? So far the only workaround I found is restarting the computer.

Comment: Do you have antivirus/firewall configured? Make sure that 5005 port is not blocked in your settings.

Comment: Do you use [Remote Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-remote-debug.html) option? Remote debugger needs to connect to the JVM that is already running in debug mode. Make sure you start the app you want to debug first with the JVM options suggested by the IDE. Then start Remote configuration to connect and debug this app.